# Display none a div if a element (span) inside this div is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like set `display: none` on a `div` if a `span` element inside this div is empty.

```html
<div class="mydiv test1">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/Googlelogo.png/1200px-Googlelogo.png" width="100px">
  <span id="myid"></span>
</div>
<div class="mydiv test2">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/Googlelogo.png/1200px-Googlelogo.png" width="100px">
  <span id="myid">100</span>
</div>
```

In this example I would like to set `display: none` on the first `div`. How can I do this using jQuery?

Comment: please make an attempt before asking

Comment: can you not do this yourself? seems simple enough...

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527)

Comment: If everyone answer is wrong, then kindly post correct answer if you have.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mydiv').each(function() {
    var eleSpan = $(this).children().siblings("span");
    if (eleSpan.html().trim().length === 0) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydiv test1">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/Googlelogo.png/1200px-Googlelogo.png" width="100px">
  <span id="myid"></span>
</div>
<div class="mydiv test2">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/Googlelogo.png/1200px-Googlelogo.png" width="100px">
  <span id="myid">100</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all spans that are children of divs, if they're empty, set the parent (div) CSS display variable to none.

```
$.each($('div > span'), function(index) {
  if($(this).is(':empty')) {
    $(this).parent().css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

See comments inline and you should never have elements with duplicate `id` values.

```js
// Get all the span elements into an array
var spans = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("span"));

// Loop over the span elements
spans.forEach(function(span){
  // Check to see if there is any text content
  if(span.textContent === ""){
     span.parentElement.classList.add("hidden");  // Hide the parent
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<div class="mydiv test1">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/Googlelogo.png/1200px-Googlelogo.png" width="100px">
  <span id="mySpan1"></span>
</div>

<div class="mydiv test2">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/Googlelogo.png/1200px-Googlelogo.png" width="100px">
  <span id="mySpan2">100</span>
</div>
```